# How can I operate on a list which is identified by a string?

Tags: perl

I would like to be able to operate on a list in Perl which is identified by a string. Code can describe this better...

```
my @colors = ("red", "white", "blue");
my @flavors = ("vanilla", "mint", "chocolate");

print "What favorites do you want to see ?";
my $fav_list = <>;  chomp($fav_list);

foreach my $favorite (???) {
    print "$favorite\n";
}
```

Given that `$fav_list` is either "colors" or "flavors", what should/could "???" in the code above be in order to print out the correct list?

Answer (score 7):

I assume you want to print the elements of `@colors` if the input is `"colors"`. The right way to do this is to use a hash, and store array references behind its keys.

[Do not use user input as variable names.](https://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)

```perl
my @colors = ("red", "white", "blue");
my @flavors = ("vanilla", "mint", "chocolate");

my %favorites = (
    colors  => \@colors,
    flavors => \@flavors,
);

print "What favorites do you want to see ?";
my $fav_list = <>;  chomp($fav_list);

foreach my $favorite ( @{ $favorites{$fav_list} } ) {
    print "$favorite\n";
}
```

The backslash `\` takes a reference to the array. That's how you build a multi-dimensional data structure in Perl. Hashes are the key/value pair (also called *dict*, *dictionary* or *object* in other languages) type data structure.

Note that it makes sense to check if the key [`exists`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists) first. Also see [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref). and [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut).

Answer (score 0):

After you get the `$fav_list`, do this:

```
my @selected_list = (); 
if( $fav_list eq "colors" ) {
    @selected_list = @colors;
}
elsif( $fav_list eq "flavors" ) {
    @selected_list = @flavors;
}

for my $favorite ( @selected_list ) {
    print "$favorite\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach to the problem

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my($answer, $choice);

my @colors  = qw/red white blue/;
my @flavors = qw/vanilla mint chocolate/;

print "What favorites do you want to see? ";

$answer = <>;
chomp($answer);

$choice = [];
$choice = \@colors  if $answer eq 'colors';
$choice = \@flavors if $answer eq 'flavors';

say for @{ $choice };
```